# extract zip file inside a zip file in python

Tags: python, zip

below are the contents of my zipfile

```
import pandas, zipfile, requests, lxml
from io import BytesIO

r  = requests.get('someurl')
z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r.contents))
z.namelist()
Out[42]: 
['abc.csv',
  xyz.zip']
```

how can i extract the contents of the xyz.zip folder?
after some trial and error, I was incidentally able to extract the contents, by some what similar code as below:

```
zz = zipfile.ZipFile(z.namelist()[1])
```

but this does not seem to work now, I am not sure what was it that i did few days back, when it did work. the error message i get is

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xyz.zip'
```

appreciate any help or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Just `ZipFile.open` the inner zip and then use that to construct a new `ZipFile` object:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r.contents)) as z:
    with z.open(z.namelist()[1]) as inner_zip:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(inner_zip) as inner:
            print(inner.namelist())
```

Answer (score 1):

ZIPPED data is sequential. Every "chunk's" decompression depends on previous chunks, in a linear "file start to file end" fashion. So you have to decode it all from start to end. Random-access decompression is not possible.

Every time a `seek()` request happens to be outsde the current decompression buffer, the entire decompression will have to restart from 0%.

This wastes huge amounts of CPU and disk reads, as Python constantly has to read the data from disk and decompress it over and over again.

For example, when I tried to directly "open" a 2 GB ZIP that was sitting inside another ZIP, and was simply looping through all files in it and reading them (which should be "2 GB" of data), I ended up with 70 GB read from disk!

We therefore need to do a one-pass decompression instead, to solve this properly.

Python's `zipfile.ZipFile()` library requires a seekable data stream, so that it can freely jump around and fetch files and metadata at various offsets in the ZIP file.

The solution:

- First of all, you MUST `.read()` the inner zipped data to place the raw `bytes` data in RAM to decompress the ZIP itself into a static location, to avoid having to constantly decompress it.
- Secondly, you must do the reading into a `io.BytesIO` buffer so that you get a SEEKABLE buffer. Thankfully, a `io.BytesIO` wrapping a `bytes` object is practically a zero-cost operation, so it's just a matter of wrapping a `BytesIO(f.read())` call to achieve that.
- THEN just open the that inner ZIP via that decompressed, seekable BytesIO data buffer. Again, since this may sound a bit confusing, I'll just clarify again that this is just the "decompressed inner ZIP file itself". The contents of that inner ZIP file are still fully compressed. We are decompressing just the "zipped ZIP-file" itself.

Here's a rough example:

```py
# Wrap the requests' "contents" bytes as a seekable BytesIO buffer and open it as "the outer ZIP".
with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.contents)) as outer_zip:
    # Open the file handle to the "inner" ZIP file inside the outer ZIP.
    with outer_zip.open("xyz.zip") as inner_zip:
        # Decompress that inner ZIP to a seekable BytesIO buffer.
        seekable_buf = io.BytesIO(inner_zip.read())
        
        # Now open the inner ZIP, to do anything you want with its contents.
        with zipfile.ZipFile(seekable_buf) as inner_contents:
            print(inner_contents.namelist())
```

And yes, this will use as many bytes of RAM as the inner ZIP file needs. But it's your only choice. Because attempting to "read live" will cause massive disk read-amplification and tons of wasted CPU usage on the constant decompression from scratch over and over again. So it's vital that you decompress to a seekable buffer *once*.

With this solution, I reduced my 70 GB disk reads to just 2 GB as intended. You can probably imagine how slow it would be to read 70 GB of data from a regular hard disk (if a user doesn't have any SSD). Which is why it matters that you decompress the data in one step, as demonstrated.

Basically, choose one:

- No buffer: Low RAM usage but massive CPU and disk-read usage. Very slow total runtime.
- My buffer solution: High RAM usage, but very fast CPU and very low disk-read usage. Very fast total runtime.